# How to set dynamically created IFRAME's charset to UTF-7?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, character-encoding

Is there a way to set dynamically created IFRAME's charset to **UTF-7**? I have tried the following but fail :-(

```
document.getElementById('test').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-7\"></head><body></body></html>";
```

The IFRAME page is still UTF-8 :-( (Using Firefox)

Answer (score 2):

UTF-7 always was considered dangerous in the net world, and almost totally useless in the rest of the dev world.

Some browsers never supported it (Chrome for example).

Link : http://scarybeastsecurity.blogspot.fr/2010/07/firefox-fixes-css-based-cross-origin.html

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 spec requires that conforming browsers must not support UTF-7:

> User agents must not support the CESU-8, UTF-7, BOCU-1 and SCSU
>   encodings.

From http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/parsing.html#determining-the-character-encoding